# Failed to launch Pixel 5 API 34: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

When I try to run flutter app (Go alive) with Android Studio I got this error:

> Failed to launch Pixel 5 API 34: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds

[image: Error image]

How to solve it and see my app running?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem I avoid it by running apps on my real device it worked for me just fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this a few times but don't recall a specific solution. Usually I quit out of the emulator program I'm using entirely and try again, sometimes manually booting up the emulator before trying to run flutter to let it connect to the running device.

One thing I do recall looking at the output, the hardware acceleration error--at one point I had to go rebuild my emulators in android studio, flipping some flags in the setup for them to enable some features. That might help if restarting doesn't.